# form dropdown.val() is not changing when passed through url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, get

I am using jquery ui autocomplete to show suggestions from db.I am passing input text and  selected value of dropdown to controller function.here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/e2qpm/)(not functional)

**Problem**: the value of column in `source: url+"?search_column="+column` is always username. How can I pass dynamic value of dropdown to autocomplete method.

**view**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/index','class="form-inline"');  ?>
  <input id='admin_auto_search' type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Search..">
  <select class="span2"  name="search_column" id="search_column">
    <option value="username">Username</option>
    <option value="created_on">Created On</option>
    <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
    <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
    <option value="company">Company</option>
    <option value="timezone">Time Zone</option>
    <option value="plan">Plan</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" value="Search" />
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    var url='<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/home/auto_complete');?>'; 
    var column=$('#search_column').val();

    $('#search_column').change(function(){
        column= $(this).val();
    });

    $("#admin_auto_search").autocomplete({
        source: url+"?search_column="+column
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

My problem is related to jquery.I am passing dropdownbox value to the auto complete method.

```
var column=$('#search_column').val();

source: url+"?search_column="+column
```

My function path is correct and is working.But whichever value I select in dropdown ,in my controller I get  the value of search_column as "username" only.

Comment: Do like this `var url="<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/home/auto_complete');?>";` [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpm/1/)

Comment: @DKM thanks. path to controller is correct.what I need is help in jquery. source: url+"?search_column="+column. In controller I always  get search_column="username".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong you have assigned the value to `column` in the `ready` function therefore it has the first value because first option is always selected try this one

I have put the `autocomplete` function inside the `onchange` so that it will have always the new value

```
$(function(){
    var url="<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/home/auto_complete');?>"; 


    $('#search_column').change(function(){

     alert($('#search_column').val()) // just for check that it is called or not 
        var column=$('#search_column').val();

     $("#admin_auto_search").autocomplete({
        source: url+"?search_column="+column
    });
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks.u r right.since i am assigning the value in ready function.the initial value is always taken.I will work with this code tommorrow and let u know.

Comment: Now autocomplete works only when a change function fires.So I made a copy of autocomplete in ready function too.Now the parameter changes.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
var url='<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/home/auto_complete');?>';
```

By

```
var url='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/home/auto_complete';
```

**Updated**

If you want to `change` the `value` every time when the user changes the `drop down value` then you have to `initialize` the plugin also, like,

```
$('#search_column').change(function(){
    column= $(this).val();
    // reinitialze autocomplete to get the changed value
    $("#admin_auto_search").autocomplete({
        source: url+"?search_column="+column
    });
});
```

Comment: my function path is correct.But search_column value is always username ie first value of drop down. It is not changing based on drop down selection